# How to fix this navigation drawer issue

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

[How to fix that http://lookingfor.bugs3.com/Screenshot_2014-05-11-13-39-25.png](http://lookingfor.bugs3.com/Screenshot_2014-05-11-13-39-25.png)

How to fix that?

I enabled the transparent statusbar with Theme.Holo.Light and got the Fragment displaying fixed, but not the Navigation drawer. How can I fix that?

Here are my activity_main.xml and drawer_list_item.xml

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"



    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem by encapsulating your activity_mail.xml to a FrameLayout.
When you do that, this is where you set the "fitsSystemWindows=true".

So, in other words, your activity_main.xml should be like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:background="@color/list_background"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:divider="@color/list_divider"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Your drawer_list_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```